# query 'sharedWithMe=false' Invalid Value?

Tags: google-drive-api

Any variation of 'sharedWithMe=false' gives me the 400 error 'Invalid Value' in reference to the q parameter:

```
sharedWithMe=false
sharedWithMe!=true
not(sharedWithMe=true)
etc...
```

It's annoying, I want to get a list of all my files using the 'allDrives' corpora (User files + Shared Drives + Shared with me) but not include the files that have been shared with me.

There's simply no way to do this without breaking it down into separate requests (1 for root Drive with 'me' in owner query, and a request for each shared drive I'm a member of.

Does anyone know why it's doing this, or can suggest an elegant solution around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is a bug

It seems that the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#file_properties) doesn't reflect the actual behavior for the `sharedWithMe` Search Query Term.

Here is a recent tracker that I found which reports this issue:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173111277

Feel free to star it to indicate that you are affected too.

### Reference

[Subscribing by starring an Issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a bug that you can solve with this workaround:
Instead to use "sharedWithMe=false", consider to use "'me' in owners", even in "q" parameter

Comment: In my experience this workaround doesn't work with the allDrives Corpora to return shared drive files.  I assume because ownership in shared drives don't include a list of the individual members.  This workaround on the User Corpora combined with the drive Corpora (listing all shared drive id's) might work, but still would be nice for a all in workaround / the sharedWithMe to work as expected